# Use only one function to show hide password for multiple fields that will clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to use only one function to hide passwords for multiple fields that will clicked. So rather than using 3 functions, I want to use one function and be active on the clicked button only. so I would like to optimize the function of this. so need to show hide pass in the click togglebtn class and corresponding input text. Let's say if togglebtn click for current password then it should work for current password fields. if togglebtn click for New password then it should work for  New password fields. same for confirming the New password.

```
 <form id="update-password-form" action="" method="post">
 <div class="updatepwd">
 <div class="form-field">
   <label for="current-password">Current Password <span class="asterisk">*</span>
   </label>
   <input type="password" name="current-password" id="passwordField" required>
   <span class="toggle-btn" onclick="togglePasswordVisibility()">️</span>
 </div>
 <div class="form-field">
   <label for="new-password">New Password <span class="asterisk">*</span>
   </label>
   <input type="password" name="new-password" id="passwordField1" required>
   <span class="toggle-btn" onclick="togglePasswordVisibility1()">️</span>
 </div>
 <div class="form-field">
   <label for="confirm-password">Confirm New Password <span class="asterisk">*</span>
   </label>
   <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="passwordField2" required>
   <span class="toggle-btn" onclick="togglePasswordVisibility2()">️</span>
 </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<script>
function togglePasswordVisibility() {
 var passwordField = document.getElementById('passwordField');
 var toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn');
 if (passwordField.type === 'password') {
   passwordField.type = 'text';
   toggleBtn.textContent = '️';
 } else {
   passwordField.type = 'password';
   toggleBtn.textContent = '️';
 }
 }

 function togglePasswordVisibility1() {
 var passwordField = document.getElementById('passwordField1');
 var toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn');
 if (passwordField.type === 'password') {
   passwordField.type = 'text';
   toggleBtn.textContent = '️';
 } else {
   passwordField.type = 'password';
   toggleBtn.textContent = '️';
 }
 }

 function togglePasswordVisibility2() {
 var passwordField = document.getElementById('passwordField2');
 var toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle-btn');
 if (passwordField.type === 'password') {
   passwordField.type = 'text';
   toggleBtn.textContent = '️';
 } else {
   passwordField.type = 'password';
   toggleBtn.textContent = '️';
 }
 }
 </script>`
```

Comment: The easiest solution would be to pass the id of the password field you want to toggle into  the function. Best practice would be to nix the inline event handlers and assign event listeners via `addEventListener()` and perhaps include the id of the password field in a data attribute of the toggle button.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code needs some adjustment to remove onclick attributes from span elements. Instead, `data-toggle-target` ( a data attribute ) is needed to link each toggle button with its corresponding password field.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-btn').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var passwordFieldId = this.getAttribute('data-toggle-target');
            var passwordField = document.getElementById(passwordFieldId);
            if (passwordField.type === 'password') {
                passwordField.type = 'text';
                this.textContent = '';
            } else {
                passwordField.type = 'password';
                this.textContent = '️';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="update-password-form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="updatepwd">
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="current-password">Current Password <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" name="current-password" id="passwordField" required>
            <span class="toggle-btn" data-toggle-target="passwordField">️</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="new-password">New Password <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" name="new-password" id="passwordField1" required>
            <span class="toggle-btn" data-toggle-target="passwordField1">️</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label for="confirm-password">Confirm New Password <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="passwordField2" required>
            <span class="toggle-btn" data-toggle-target="passwordField2">️</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When a button is clicked, the function identifies which password field to toggle based on the `data-toggle-target` attribute of the clicked button.